# c++ pass different classes into function

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

I may be going about this completely the wrong way but it's getting late and its driving me a little mad.

I have a function in my base class that should allow me to create new objects of derived classes. However where it's says Melee I want it to be interchangeable with my other derived classes. I can't figure how to pass in a different class so it will create an object of that class.

```
void BaseUnit::CreateNewUnit(vector<BaseUnit*>& MyVector)
{
    UnitID++;
    MyVector.push_back(new Melee());

}
```

Comment: Does it need to be determined at compile-time or run-time?

Comment: run-time, they will press a key and it will create a different unit accordingly

Comment: You will need to create some kind of switch statement or alternative to convert the input to the type. Consider not making a different class for each unit, but a single unit class with members for melee strength, ranged strength, display graphic etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "[prototype design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern)".

Put in a `std::map` the associations key -> prototype and you're done: when the user press a key, you lookup into the map, extract the prototype and pass it to `CreateNewUnit`. Inside CreateNewUnit, you will use `Prototype::Clone()`

```
class BaseUnit
{
public:
    ... // your methods
    virtual BaseUnit* Clone() = 0;
};

class Melee : public BaseUnit
{
public:
    BaseUnit* Clone() { return new Melee(); }
};

void BaseUnit::CreateNewUnit(vector<BaseUnit*>& MyVector, BaseUnit* prototype )
{
    UnitID++;
    MyVector.push_back( prototype -> Clone() );
}

int main()
{
    std::map< char, BaseUnit* > prototypes;
    prototypes[ 'a' ] = new Melee();
    prototypes[ 'b' ] = new OtherUnit();
    ...

    std::vector< BaseUnit* > units;

    char selection = GetKeyPressed();
    BaseUnit::CreateNewUnit( units, prototypes[ selection ] );
}
```

The benefit of this solution is that when you need to add a new Unit type in your application you must just add a new entry in the prototypes map.

And by the way: with a little effort you can even avoid that, if the classes derived from BaseUnit register themselves in a global "prototypes" map.

Comment: I would rather store a map of pointers to functions which return the new object type, rather than requiring the objects can be copied.

Comment: @NeilKirk My code doesn't require the objects can be copied.

Comment: @Daniele - but it requires basically unused object instances just for the sake of calling a virtual method on them. And unfortunately, you can't have a static virtual, so I'd say a map of function pointers is a better solution. It does defeat the purpose, the map will introduce overhead and will add no extra flexibility, whereas with function pointers you can register new types from dynamic libraries.

Comment: @NeilKirk well, yes, if your objects are hevvyweight maybe a map of std::function maybe it's better (but no function pointers, please :-). Ideally, i'd like a template factory function, so that I don't need to define a function for each concrete class.

Comment: @Daniele - contrary to what modernist evangelists may say, there is nothing wrong with good old raw pointers. They were good for decades and still are. But if it makes you feel better having them in a thin wrapper - knock yourself out. Personally I think people are loosing sight of the intent behind recent C++ features, and use them in some sort of a trendy fashion even in instances they are counterproductive.

Comment: @ddriver - there is nothing wrong with good old raw pointers... except you cannot use lambda with them; and in this specific case, I'd like to use lambda to initialize the map (just to avoid the definition of a function for each concrete class). And be sure: I'm not the kind that follow trends and self-proclaimed guru :-)

Comment: Just what I was saying, if you DO NEED to use a new feature, use it. In your case you need to. Some people actually do stuff as crazy as `auto main() -> int` which is plain out silly.

Answer (score 0):

This probably gives you an idea of how to do it:
1. change the function signature to include the derived object pointer as a second parameter,

```
void BaseUnit::CreateNewUnit(vector<BaseUnit*>& MyVector, const BaseUnit* derived) {
    UnitID++;
    MyVector.push_back(derived);
}
```

2. Call the above function when you press a key, if a key is pressed, create a new derived object and call ur function:

   Melee *m = new Melee();

   unit.CreateNewUnit(myVector,m);

Comment: This will create a `Melee` unit on the stack, register it in the vector and result in a dangling pointer after the function returns, resulting in undefined behavior and most likely a crash.

Answer (score 0):

I would either pass a pointer to the unit:

```
void BaseUnit::CreateNewUnit(vector<BaseUnit*>& MyVector, BaseUnit* unit)
{
    UnitID++;
    MyVector.push_back(unit);
}
```

or pass the key pressed or some other id:

```
void BaseUnit::CreateNewUnit(vector<BaseUnit*>& MyVector, char type)
{
    switch(type) //this would be the key pressed
    {
    case '1':
         MyVector.push_back(new Melee());
         UnitID++;
         break;//this would be continued for all possible units
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the second solution, I'm always tempted to make an array (or a `map`) of factory functions rather than a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be determined at compile time you can either use templates methods or create a method for each class. This is called factory method, it's a design pattern.  Note that the 'hint'  to the factory here is the template parameter.

If you want it to be determined at runtime, you need to identify the relevant class in some way, a 'hint'  for the factory. Most of the times this would be an enum or a string. Again, read about the factory design pattern and factory method.

Answer (score -1):

If you need that at compile time, you can simply go for a factory template. If different classes have different parameters that need to be passed, you should use a variadic template:

```
#include <utility> 

class Factory {
    ...
    template <typename Derived, typename ...Args>
    BaseUnit * create(Args &&... args)
    { 
        return new Derived(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Then you can simply create a factory and call `factory.create(Melee, optional_arguments)` or whatever type, and a template specialization will be created to instantiate that particular type with the supplied arguments.

If you need a "runtime dispatch" creation function, you could have something like an `enum Type` in `BaseUnit` or some other id that lists every possible derived type, and have a `create(BaseUnit::Type type)` method with a `switch (type)` statement and a case for every object type that creates the appropriate type. Naturally, this can be used in conjunction with the template factory listed above.

A switch statement will be considerably more efficient than a map, and besides, a map will not really make sense if it is populated "statically". A map only makes sense when you want to register a new object creation method during the runtime. In that case you can have a map of a type id and a pointer to a function, returning a new `BaseType` derived. This way you can for example register extra functions, loaded from a dynamic library, look up the function pointer based on the type id and use it to instantiate object of that type. But that's only in case you need runtime registration. Otherwise stick to the previous solutions. This will only be justified if you have something like "plugins" - dynamic libraries which provide a set of extra types and the appropriate functions to create them, so you can load a library, register its components in the map, and be able to instantiate types which are not present during the implementation of the "core logic" of the game. Naturally, this all has to rely on polymorphic interfaces that the core logic is design around in order to work, otherwise it won't. Also, for this solution you might want the id to be a string rather than an integer, since it offers more flexibility and does not have the restrictions of a switch statement.

Also note I did not include your `vector<BaseUnit*>& MyVector` - IMO that shouldn't be an argument you pass, but a local member to your game class which you can access directly without needing to have it as an argument.

Also, follow proper coding conventions, do not use member methods or objects or parameters with upper case. It is just confusing.